# How to check a String if it's an ASCII or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9

For example something like:

```
"ASCII".is_ascii? # => true

"تجربة".is_ascii? # => false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your strings are Unicode (and they really *should* be, nowadays), you can simply check that all code points are 127 or less. The bottom 128 code points of Unicode are ASCII.

Answer (score 62):

There is a bult-in Ruby string method right for you.

```
str.ascii_only? # → true or false
```

Returns true for a string which has only ASCII characters.

```
"abc".force_encoding("UTF-8").ascii_only?          #=> true
"abc\u{6666}".force_encoding("UTF-8").ascii_only?  #=> false
```